# Can __call__ return something in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand some program with inside a code like that:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # some initializations 
        pass

    def __call__(self, a, b):
        return a+b

x = foo()
x(2, 3)
```

Is a return call inside `__call__` an error? It doesn't raise any errors but how can we access the return value in `__call__` then?

Comment: `Is a return call inside __call__ an error?` What? Why would it be? I don't understand your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can return a value from `__call__`, and the value will be used as the return value of the call itself.

Using your example:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # some initializations 
        pass

    def __call__(self, a, b):
        return a+b

obj = foo()
print obj(1, 2) # Prints `3`
```